# File path errors when reading a file

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game for Android & iOS and using this script to take a screenshot and apply it to a sprite image when you reach a highscore. `getScreenshot()` is called to initialize. It was working fine in the player on windows using `Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + screenshotFilename;` but I guessed that iOS probably required the `\` instead but I'm still receiving a NullReferenceException in Xcode for function `LoadPNG();`

```
public static string screenshotFilename = "MM_Screenshot.png";
string pathToImage;

public void getScreenshot() {
    pathToImage = Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + screenshotFilename;
    Application.CaptureScreenshot (pathToImage);
    StartCoroutine("LoadScreenshot");
}

IEnumerator LoadScreenshot() {
    Sprite NewSprite = new Sprite();
    Texture2D SpriteTexture = LoadPNG(pathToImage);
    GameObject.Find("CaptureImage").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(SpriteTexture,new Rect(0, 0, SpriteTexture.width, SpriteTexture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.8f));
    yield return null;
}

public static Texture2D LoadPNG(string filePath) {

    Texture2D tex = null;
    byte[] fileData;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))     {
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(fileData); //..this will auto-resize the texture dimensions.
    }
    return tex;
}
```